# Unable to load static files in Django Production

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I am trying to run the app with `DEBUG=False`

Below is my setting file configuration

```py
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/')
```

After running python manage.py collectstatic, all the static files in the app path are copied to staticfiles directory (mentioned in `STATIC_ROOT` path).

When loading the webpage, the static files are failed to get load.

**Error message:**

> GET **/static**/dist/bootstrap-4.0.0-dist/js/bootstrap.min.14d449eb8876.js HTTP/1.1" 404 77
>
> GET /**static**/dist/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.min.31f649694651.js HTTP/1.1" 404 77
>
> GET /**static**/js/base.1332bbb46ac5.js HTTP/1.1" 404 77
>
> GET /**static**/crsummary/dist/amcharts4/core.ea1ec0eb6727.js HTTP/1.1" 404 77

Looking at the error message, apps is trying to load the `bootstrap.min.14d449eb8876.js` from path `/static/\*/\*` but the actual file location is `staticfiles/\*/\*`

I am not sure what configuration that I have missed out here.

Comment: Which webserver you're using? Nginx or Apache? It could help if you can provide the configuration for the webserver

Comment: Where are the static files when you're not in production? Are they not in a folder called `static/`? `python manage.py collectstatic` simply takes all of your static files and puts them into one folder (`staticfiles/` in your case), but it doesn't mean they will be served from there. As @ToanQuocHo asked, which server are you using?

Comment: I haven't used any external web servers like Apache, but I tried using development server itself (provided by Django) to test if DEBUG=False works. I have given my computer's IP address in ALLOWED_HOST. Will this error occur if we do  not use any external web servers while deploying Django in production ?

Comment: It won't work as your expected, and it's very not good for your app when running using `runserver` command. If you still want to follow this way, make sure that your static url config on your `urls.py` is not stay inside `if settings.DEBUG:` condition block. But I really not recommend you to even try this.

Comment: I think you have to set DEBUG=True when running in runserver. Please read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

Comment: @ToanQuocHo Thanks for the clarification. I will try running the app in Apache or Nginx and check it the issue persists

Comment: Mostly I will use reverse proxy (Nginx) to pass request into Django app, run by using Gunicorn. And for static files, I also use Nginx to serve static files (set alias to point to STATIC_ROOT folder).

Answer (score 2):

Django doesn't allow to load staticfiles when codes in production, instead of using aws or any other online content delivery network

If you really wan't to load staticfiles from the codes directory , you need to install whitenoise , and define it in your middleware, staticfiles, and installed_apps

for more you can search for use and settings whitenoise in django

Answer (score 0):

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=" {%static 'app1/css/freelancer.css' %}" />
```

Load the static files like this.

```
{% load static %}
<img class="img-fluid" src="{% static 'app1/img/portfolio/ai.png' %}" alt="">
```

Load the image like this.

Before that , Required to specify the Base directory and static directory

```
STATIC_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[STATIC_DIR,]
```

Base directory

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)